# pyspark regex to match domain\username pattern

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have string with domain\username in an array. I want to match it and replace it.

The string has following pattern:

```
[, DESKTOP-XXQYY56\Adminaccount, ] [, MB4345XX\adminaccount, ]
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
df2= df1.withColumn(
    'str1',
     regexp_replace(
        'str',
        r'^([A-Za-z0-9]+(-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)+(\\?([A-Za-z0-9])+)*',
        'AB22'
    )
)
```

I am not able to match the pattern correctly. I want to match the string and replace it. Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match and replace? The example above is the example string including the square brackets? Try omitting the anchor `^`

Comment: I have data in the format domain\user E.g.  [, DESKTOP-XXQYY56\Adminaccount, ] [, MB4345XX\adminaccount, ]. I want to find this data and replace it with 'XXXX'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match that format and replace the `domain\user` with XXXX you might use 2 capturing groups for the opening `[,` and closing `, ]`

You could omit the anchor `^` and in this part `([A-Za-z0-9])+` move the quantifier `+` to the character class `[A-Za-z0-9]+` or else you would repeat the group matching a single char.

If you are not using the capturing groups separately for further processing you could turn them into non capturing groups `(?:`

The pattern might look like

```
(\[, )[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(?:\\?[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(, \])
```

In parts

- `(\[, )` Capture **group 1** match `[,`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed in the character class
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `-[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match `-` and match 1+ times any of the listed
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\\?[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match optional `\` and 1+ times any of the listed
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `(, \])` Capture **group 2** match `, ]`

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups

```
$1XXXX$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvfp3v/1/)